# Hightlight image within a vertical manager

Tags: blackberry, bitmap

So i have 3 images in a vertical field manager and each image is clickable and proceeds to the correct url. all that works. the only problem at this time is that when i scroll (up or down), i don't know which image is currently focused. i don't know until the browser opens the corresponding url.

so is there any way to get a border or a highlight to appear under my images (or within the manager) so that i can definitely see which image is currently focused? so if you think of a list, your selections are highlighted as you scroll up and down. i want something similar to that with my application.

thank you for your help.

ac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using the setSpace(int,int) method on the bitmap field worked great. this allowed me to see a border around the element that had focus.

Answer (score 1):

override inline the bitmapfield drawFocus method. Something like this

```
protected void drawFocus(Graphics graphics, boolean on){
   graphics.setBackgroundColor(0x00204020);
   graphics.drawRect(0, 0, getBitmapWidth(), getBitmapHeight());

}
```